# Collect call for a Map?

Tags: java, call, collect

So let's say we had two ArrayLists for two Objects that were both populated with things. For ease of understanding, one is an ArrayList of License plates, and the other are of cars.

All the cars get assigned a valid license plate and then the car gets the plate's number...

```
cars.addAll(plates.stream().filter(plate -> plate.getStatus() == PLATE_GOOD)
  .map(plate -> new Car(plate.getNumber(), modelT())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

But then the owners of the cars needed to register their plates and cars into a Map of plates and cars.

```
registered = new HashMap<Plate, Car>();

for(Plate plate : plates)
     if(plate.getStatus() == PLATE_GOOD)
          for(Car car : cars)
              if(car.getNumber() == plate.getNumber()) {
                   registered.put(plate, car);
                   break;
              }
```

But the DMV demanded that there be no loops and that the owners would use a collect call.

TL;DR Collect call featuring multiple predicates in order to populate a map of objects?

Comment: Use `Collectors.toMap(...)`.

Comment: @Andreas Sure, but that doesn't rectify my understanding of multiple parameters in this case. But thank you for your time and I'm glad to know there is a loop-less solution to this personal quandary assuming your comment implies this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get what you want with the statement you're already using, because it produces a list of `Car`, but there's no connection between the `Car` and the `Plate`.  Both have a plate number, but that doesn't allow you to figure out the `Plate` if you have a `Car`, or vice versa, without going through the kind of double loop you've posted--or without setting up a `Map` that maps a plate number to a plate or a car.  But if you need a `Map<Plate, Car>`, you shouldn't have to set up a `Map<String, Plate>` or `Map<String, Car>` [assuming the plate number is a string], although that map could be a useful thing to have anyway.

I'd suggest creating the `Map<Plate, Car>` first:

```
Map<Plate, Car> carMap = plates.stream().filter(plate -> plate.getStatus() == PLATE_GOOD)
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), plate -> new Car(plate.getNumber(), modelT())));
```

This will create a new `Car` for each plate **and** set up the map.  `Collectors.toMap()` needs two parameters that are functions that operate on a `Plate`.  The first will become the key of the map, and the second will be the value.  `Function.identity()` just means we use the `Plate` itself as the key.  Or you could equivalently use `plate -> plate`.

To get a list of cars, use `carMap.values()`.  This returns a `Collection` (not necessarily a `List`), but you can add it to a list with `addAll`.  This won't necessarily return the cars in the same order as the plates.  If you need them in the same order, you could do this after creating `carMap`:

```
List<Car> carList = plates.stream().filter(plate -> plate.getStatus() == PLATE_GOOD)
.map(plate -> carMap.get(plate)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I don't know of a way to do both at once (add the car to a list, and add the plate/car to a map), except by writing your own code to add to the list and the map:

```
plates.stream().filter(plate -> plate.getStatus() == PLATE_GOOD)
.forEachOrdered(plate -> { 
    Car car = new Car(plate.getNumber(), modelT()); 
    carList.add(car); 
    carMap.put(plate, car); });
```

`forEachOrdered` is needed to ensure the operations are performed in the right order.  **Note:** I haven't tested this last one.  I *think* it will work without synchronization, but I'm not sure.

Comment: plates.stream().filter(plate -> plate.getStatus() == PLATE_GOOD)
.forEachOrdered(plate -> {
    Car car = new Car(plate.getNumber(), modelT()); 
    carList.add(car);
    carMap.put(plate, car); });
This worked perfectly, initialized the car arraylist and then populated the map at the same time which is so much more efficent than having the two goes at it that I had done before. Thank you sir! <3 collect calls.